# Code to format JSON data and append hardcoded data to create a flat .txt file

Tags: python

Source Data::

```
json_data = [{"studentid": 1, "name": "ABC", "subjects": ["Python", "Data Structures"]},
             {"studentid": 2, "name": "PQR", "subjects": ["Java", "Operating System"]}]

Hardcoded_Val1 = 10
Hardcoded_Val2 = 20
Hardcoded_Val3 = str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Need to create a flat .txt file with the below data.

```
ID,DEPT,"studentid|name|subjects",execution_dt
10,20,"1|ABC|Python,Data Structures",2023-06-01
10,20,"2|PQR|Java,Operating System",2023-06-01
```

I am very new in python. Have already tried to figure it out to achieve it but couldn't. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import json


json_data = [{"studentid": 1, "name": "ABC", "subjects": ["Python", "Data Structures"]},
             {"studentid": 2, "name": "PQR", "subjects": ["Java", "Operating System"]}]

Hardcoded_Val1 = 10
Hardcoded_Val2 = 20
Hardcoded_Val3 = str(datetime.datetime.now())

profile = str(Hardcoded_Val1) + ',' + str(Hardcoded_Val2) + ',"' + str(json_data) + '",' + Hardcoded_Val3
        
print(profile)
#data = json.dumps(profile, indent=True)
#print(data)
data_list = []
for data_info in profile:
   data_list.append(data_info.replace(", '", '|'))
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_list)
data_df.to_csv(r'E:\DataLake\api_fetched_sample_output.txt', sep='|', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bypass using pandas for this and just build the string manually primarily using a list comprehension and `join()`.

```py
import datetime
import csv

Hardcoded_Val1 = 10
Hardcoded_Val2 = 20
Hardcoded_Val3 = str(datetime.date.today())
json_data = [
    {"studentid": 1, "name": "ABC", "subjects": ["Python", "Data Structures"]},
    {"studentid": 2, "name": "PQR", "subjects": ["Java", "Operating System"]}
]

csv_data = []
for row in json_data:
    keys = "|".join(row.keys())
    values = "|".join([
        ",".join(value) if isinstance(value, list) else str(value)
        for value in row.values()
    ])
    csv_data.append(dict([
        ("ID", Hardcoded_Val1),
        ("DEPT", Hardcoded_Val2),
        (keys, values),
        ("execution_dt", Hardcoded_Val3)
    ]))

with open("out.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as file_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_out, fieldnames=list(csv_data[0].keys()))
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(csv_data)
```

This will produce a file with the following contents:

```
ID,DEPT,studentid|name|subjects,execution_dt
10,20,"1|ABC|Python,Data Structures",2023-06-02
10,20,"2|PQR|Java,Operating System",2023-06-02
```

Comment: The actual expectation is below,

```
ID,DEPT,"studentid|name|subjects",execution_dt
10,20,"1|ABC|Python,Data Structures",2023-06-01
10,20,"2|PQR|Java,Operating System",2023-06-01
```

Comment: Please try to specify the accurate expected output when you post the question. This new requirement completely changes the solution.

Comment: Apologies for the same, I have tried to give more clarity on the expectation. Will keep in my mind. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have tried one more scenario but getting one error <'str' object has no attribute 'keys'> while executing this code where json_data = {"studentid": 1, "name": "ABC", "subjects": "Python"}. I have tried json.dumps() but could not able to resolve it. Is it possible for you help.

Comment: Is your json data already a dictionary or are you loading text from a file that wants to be parsed into a dictionary with json.load()

Comment: Yes, my json data already a dictionary. Basically I am pulling the data using, 
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(<token>) 
api_data = json.dumps(graph.get_object(id=<account_id>, fields=<field_ids>))

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help.

```
import pandas as pd

json_data = [
    {"studentid": 1, "name": "ABC", "subjects": ["Python", "Data Structures"]},
    {"studentid": 2, "name": "PQR", "subjects": ["Java", "Operating System"]}
]

# Convert JSON to DataFrame
df = pd.json_normalize(json_data, "subjects", ["studentid", "name"])

# Rename columns
df.columns = ["subject", "studentid", "name"]

# Save DataFrame to CSV
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: That seems like a productive start.

Comment: Hi CandleWax,

Here you are normalizing one column. But, suppose if  I want to normalize multiple columns then what needs to be done here, could you please suggest.